Deduplicate large set of small strings (or hashes)
I have, eventually, around 10-20 billion strings of a length of 10 ASCII characters which I'm trying to deduplicate. The values are distributed quite nicely between the starting character as it's a random string. My wish is to have them in a database, because it's easier/faster to add/check some extra keys in the future.
I've tried PostgreSQL with a single PK varchar(10) column with the value, this performs somewhat OK but still takes around 12 hours or so to get to 100M records. Using
INSERT INTO table (id) 
VALUES ('1000', 'values') 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING

Where the input might be 200-400M non duplicated. Also tried a BYTEA PK column with the SHA256, but I guess because it's more data 44 characters that it isn't better, and I also have to store the value in a second column.
Tried partitioning, but then I need to create the partitions myself, and I'm not sure if I need to update them, or only add the partition once for every starting character. Also, don't know if partitioning helps for this usecase.
Did also tried to setup Clickhouse, but that already made 60K files in the first 12-16 hours or so, even without a database so abandoned that. Feels like Elasticsearch which is also active when literally nothing is happening.
Does anybody have something better than my current workaround of saving all the data to thousands of files with the first 2 starting letters and then duplicating the files one-by-one? Which takes only 3 hours in total, so 10-20 times fast than a database, which feels wrong to me :) But that is more a one-time workaround, not usefull when you do a lot of small adds in the future.
The data is currently stored in multiple text files like:
dni2X2qjrj
CBvMBHC0XT
dV9wixX8IX
pN5FTsP1Bn
RiRn61pmVa
2mVV6R2KpF
4KIeZQIrPW
4tF6hrPnEN
UFAPo8KkNV
ePFgMCmA0Y

Currently retrying it with MongoDB, and only a single column/'field', with BulkWriteAsync (again). At 282 million records/documents now. Speed varies, reason currently CPU is also taken on other things as well. Speed is about 3 seconds for 10K. Which will take at least 21 days to process 6 billion, because it will get much slower by time 

Where are the data stored now? Can you write an example of the data?

Are the data related or do you want to create a relationship between them?

Added an example. No, purely deduplication right now, no relations. Thanks!

Load the data into a table without a Primary Key, then use select distinct to extract the unique values.  Load these into a table with a Primary Key, for unique checking in future.
Something like this:
create table raw_data 
( value char(10) not null 
); 

-- lots of 
insert into raw_data values ( ? ); 


create table unique_data 
( value char(10) not null 
, primary key ( value ) 
);

insert into unique_data 
select distinct 
  value 
from raw_data ; 


-- drop table raw_data ;   -- (tidy up) 


but if the data don't need a relation wouldn't be better to use a NoSQL?

Your choice of DBMS depends entirely on what you intend to do with this data /after/ you've deduplicated it.
Also, the fact that you care about the uniqueness of these things tends to make me think that other things to /do/ relate to it!

Currently MongoDB is at 318M. For now it's cleaning, in the end it will be loaded into a RabbitMQ/Redis or other distributed system to process them further. But for now it's cleaning.
OK, I could test if that is quicker / works. Hope I have/get time for that tomorrow. Thanks!

I'm sorry, I haven't tried this yet, and I'm not sure I will (sorry!) as a DISTINCT will also not be fast in any way. In the end I got 2 billion rows in MongoDB, retrieving the first page was like 0.012s, and then trying to get the second page it just exploded . Also tried PostgreSQL and MariaDB. PostgreSQL was slower in the beginning, and MariaDB became slower than MongoDB after 5 million rows.. For now the gathering of the IDs is almost finished, I'll then run the deduplication with files and call it a day.
